# Binding troubles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to bind my query result to My datagrid, Nothing Is currently being displayed. If i can get guidance to Bind please.

```
public int Indepth { get; set; }
public ReportGridViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
{
    EndDateTo = DateTime.Today;
    StartDateTo = DateTime.Today;
    using (var ctx = DB.Get())
    {
         var query = from z in ctx.Interactions
             where z.ActivityDate >= StartDateTo && z.ActivityDate <= EndDateTo
             select new {Indepth = z.Indepth};
         Indepth = query.Count();
    }
}
```

Xaml Bindings:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="StartDateTo" SelectedDate="{Binding StartDateTo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<DatePicker x:Name="EndDateTo" SelectedDate="{Binding EndDateTo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="InDepth" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Indepth}"/>
```

I'm thinking it has to do with my Date Paramters, But I'm not entirely sure.

Used code below to test bindings and it worked

```
using (var ctx = DB.Get())
        {
            Items.AddRange(
                ctx.Interactions.Select(
                x => new InteractionDTO()
                {
                    ActivityDate = x.ActivityDate,
                    Indepth = x.Indepth
                }
                )
           );
        }
```

Comment: This isn't enough code to know exactly what could be wrong. We need to see all of the Xaml, Xaml.cs, and the `ReportGridViewModel`. But you problem is very solvable.

Comment: The code is fairly large. So I simplified it as easy as I could. I did  `MessageBox.Show(query.Count().ToString());` and it showed 55000 which is a sign meaning the query works. Can the column `Bind` to an integer? Do i Have to change Indepth to another value type?

Comment: Where is your `DataContext` set? That's what we need to see first, then we can identify whether or not your bindings will work. Also, check the output window in VS for any binding failure messages after your run your app.

Comment: Does the class in the first listing implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?  If it does not, the binding won't work because WPF can't detect that changes have been made in the background.

Comment: @TonyVitabile, not totally true. It can detect changes to the data context as a whole, but any properties on the data context that are bound to require a call to `OnPropertyChanged`. Very subtle, but noteworthy.

Comment: I've binded Data to many of my other raddatagrids. I rewrote the code to test bindings, Updated above. And it worked, But I wasnt a summary instead. Any tips.

Answer (score 0):

As @WilliamCustode mentioned in a comment, you haven't provided *enough code to know exactly what could be wrong*. However, all of these `Binding` problems are solved in the same way. You need to simplify the situation and be methodical.

First we make sure that the `DataContext` is correctly set to an instance of your `ReportGridViewModel`. Next, we check the data:

```
using (var ctx = DB.Get())
{
     var query = from z in ctx.Interactions
         where z.ActivityDate >= StartDateTo && z.ActivityDate <= EndDateTo
         select new {Indepth = z.Indepth};
     Indepth = query.Count();
} // <-- put a breakpoint here
```

With a breakpoint, you can test to see if your `Indepth` property *actually* has a value. If that's all good, we check for `Binding` errors in the Visual Studio Output Window. You should see something like this:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Some' property not found on 'object' ''NameOfDataBoundObject' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=SomePath; DataItem='NameOfDataBoundObject' (Name=''); target element is 'TypeOfUiElement' (Name='NameOfUiElement'); target property is 'PropertyName' (type 'TypeOfProperty')

Always pay attention to these errors because they can help you to understand what your problem is. Having said all that, I think that I've just noticed what your problem actually is... you seem to be trying to bind to your `Indepth` property from the view model, but your `GridViewDataColumn` does not have the view model as its `DataContext`. Presumably, you have something like this:

```
<telerik:GridView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <telerik:GridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="InDepth" 
            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Indepth}" />
        ...
    <.telerik:GridView.Columns>
</telerik:GridView>
```

The `GridViewDataColumn` will have its `DataContext` set to the relevant data item from the `SomeCollection` collection property and *not* the view model. However, you *can* still access the view model using a `RelativeSource Binding` something like this:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="InDepth" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Indepth, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourWindow}}}" />
```

In this example, `YourWindow` is the name of the `Window`, or `UserControl` that has the view model set as its `DataContext` and `YourPrefix` is the XAML Namespace to that class. Finally, going back to the imaginary error shown above, you would have had one saying something like `'Indepth' property not found on 'object' ''NameOfClassInSomeCollection'` and *that* would have been your clue to locate your problem.